# How to use web component into React Js?

Tags: html, reactjs, css, material-ui

currently i don't have any idea about web component related

my ultimate aim is i want to use google material component in react js project ?

here is google material web component available

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web

how to use the web component in react js ?

**Thanks**

J.Jayaprakash.

Comment: The question is too broad. Why did you choose https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web ? There are Material libs for React, did you check them?

Comment: yes i checked so many UI Libray is available but  we need to use only google material component only so i  choose.  

 https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react

Comment: You can use Material UI or material-components-web-react if you want to do this with React. Why bother with Web Components?

Comment: no  currenly people are moving into web component only that's why i am asking about web component.  it's  treading   ?

Comment: Asking for opinions is off-topic on SO. But from my experience, Web Components are viable option but far from de facto standard for components. You can check Google Trends if you're interested in popular technologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a boilerplate: https://github.com/takanabe/react-redux-material_ui-boilerplate

It use https://material-ui.com/

I recommand to refer to https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto instead before coding.